# window.scrollTo not scrolling to provided id

Tags: jquery, scrolltop, scrollto

I am working on a single document file. I want to scroll to the desired section with id="projectpage" when an anchor with id="about" is clicked.

```
<a class="nav-link page-scroll"  href="" id="about">About Me</a>

<section id="aboutpage">
```

I tried using

```
$('a#about').click(function(){
    $(window).scrollTo(0, document.getElementById('projectpage').offsetTop);
    
  });
```

or even

```
$('#about').click(function(){
    $(window).scrollTo(0, document.getElementById('projectpage').offsetTop);
    
  });
```

but nothing works.

When I click on the anchor with id="about", it just redirects me to the index.html(the main HTML with all document) file itself rather than going to the offsetTop of id="projectpage".

Comment: Is it `#aboutpage` or `#projectpage` ???

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default behavior of an anchor.... Using [.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

And replace `$(window)` for just `window`... You don't need jQuery to lookup for the window when you wish to apply a vanilla JS method on it.

```js
$('#about').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById('aboutpage').offsetTop);
});
```

```css
section{
  height: 200px;
  border-top: 2px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="" id="about">About Me</a>

<section id="somethingElse1">...</section>
<section id="somethingElse2">...</section>
<section id="somethingElse3">...</section>
<section id="aboutpage">About</section>
<section id="somethingElse4">...</section>
<section id="somethingElse5">...</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a small example for you using `scrollIntoView()`. Also, take into account the need for `event.preventDefault()` to disable the default ability to click on the tag `a`.

In addition, `scrollIntoView()` has a parameter with an animation transition effect:

```
behavior: "smooth"
```

Note: since you are using `jquery`, I see no point in casting to an element like:

```
document.getElementById('aboutpage')
```

Appeal, as in `jquery`:

```
$("#aboutpage")[0]
```

```js
$('a#about').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
    $("#aboutpage")[0].scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth"
  }); 
});
```

```css
#first {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: green;
}

#aboutpage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="nav-link page-scroll"  href="" id="about">About Me</a>

<section id="first"></section>
<section id="aboutpage"></section>
```