# How do I create a button that when clicked scrolls down to a different section on the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a button on a landing page, I would like users to be redirected to another section (in my case the contact section) on the same page when they click this button. I have tried doing this but it's not working

```js
       document.querySelector('#btn').
       addEventListener('click',()=>{
       document.querySelector('#contact').
       style.scrollBehavior = 'smooth'
})
```

```html
  <button id="btn">Discover Now</button>
  <section id = "contact" class="contact"></section>
```

I have also tried this

```
<button><a href="#contact">Discover Now</a></button>
```

but did not work, where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: It might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65385050/window-scrollto-not-scrolling-to-provided-id/65385210#65385210

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_smooth_scroll_jquery

Answer (score 2):

In **CSS**, set `scroll-behavior` property like this:

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

In **HTML**, add an `a` tag with a `href` attribute refering to certain section:

```
<a href="#contact">Click</a>
<div id="contact"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
<a href="#contact">Discover Now</a>
```

You can't put a link inside a button. Use CSS to make the link look like a button.

Answer (score 0):

You having a `;` inside a javascript object `{ behavior:'smooth' ; }` which make an error syntax, you also could press `f12` to check the console logs, im sure it yelling at you the same when you click the button, something like `unexpected token ;`:

```
<button id="btn">Discover Now</button>
<section id = "contact" class="contact">

<script>
   document.querySelector('#btn').
   addEventListener('click',()=>{
   document.querySelector('#contact').
     scrollIntoView({
     behavior:'smooth'
   });
</script>
```

Comment: There are no errors in the console and I can't quite see the error in the function

Comment: it should yell error when you click the button `{ behavior:'smooth' ; }` the `;` in an javascript object, is invalid

Comment: the  semicolon is not inside the curly braces

Comment: it show in your example..., if it not, could you update it ?

Comment: as in your example, after you remove the semicolon, it work as expected

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing section tag.

```
<section id = "contact" class="contact">
   lorem ipsum
</section>
```

You may want to check on this page for explanations:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section1

Comment: In the full code, I have a closing section tag, I should edit the post

Comment: Yes, has the issue been soved yet

Answer (score -1):

Why use javascript? You can do this with just html. All you need is:

```
<a href="#contact">Discover now</a>
<div id="contact">Contact section</div>
```

Neither of your examples are valid html btw.

Comment: What reason could make this not work? I have tried it and still nothing

Comment: Your document is not long enough.

Comment: I think that's, I just have 3sections all around 100vh each, I am going to add more though

Answer (score -1):

using scrollit it is easy to customize  http://www.bytemuse.com/scrollIt.js/

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="#contact">Discover now</a>
```

That's what i recommend using.
You can use javascript with this

```
<button id="contact">Discover now</button>

document.getElementById("contact").addEventListener("click", function(){
    location.hash = "contact";
});
```